# After installing textgreek, lgrenc.def still not available

Tags: texlive

I installed MacTeX's texlive 2014basic to avoid having to download too much all at once.  One of the papers I wanted to build uses the `textgreek` package.  Though I can install that with tlmgr

```
sudo tlmgr install textgreek
```

This still results in the following error when I try to `pdflatex` the paper

```
! Package textgreek Error: Cannot find the file lgrenc.def.
```

I can't figure out which `tlmgr` package to install to get that file generated.  I wonder also if I should just be using a `tlmgr generate` command.  But I can't tell what arguments I should pass to that (`tlmgr help` doesn't seem to provide a relevant example).

Comment: Is it on your system? Try `kpsewhich lgrenc.def`; if that doesn't return anything, then try `locate lgrenc.def`.

Comment: You need to install `sudo tlmgr install greek-fontenc` (and also `babel-greek`, I guess).

Comment: @egreg: that gets me to a `No file LGRcmr.fd` and `This NFSS system isn't set up properly`.  I guess that's progress.  It's annoying that `tlmgr` doesn't seem to have given me the dependencies I need though when it installed `textgreek`

Comment: Install the full MacTeX and live happier.

Comment: @MichaelNorrish `lgrenc.def` is in `greek-fontenc`, as egreg mentioned. The `LGRcmr.fd` not found error is a problem with your usage. Concerning the `tlmgr` dependency comment: yes, `tlmgr` does not guarantee inter-package dependecies. We try to keep inter-collection dependencies working and up2date, but also this is not guaranteed.

Comment: @norbert I have installed `greek-fontenc`, `textgreek`, `babel-greek` and `cbfonts` but I still get `No file LGRcmr.fd.` What do you mean by "...error is a problem with your usage"?

Comment: `lgrcmr.fd` is in the `cbfonts-fd` package ("LaTeX font description files for the CB Greek fonts"),

Answer (score 11):

**Note**: this is a Debian, and Debian derivates, [packaging bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=778917) and was fixed in `texlive-latex-extra` version 2017.20170724-1

---

- The Tex package `textgreek` is in the Debian package `texlive-latex-extra`.
- The Tex package `greek-fontenc` is in the Debian package `texlive-lang-greek`.
- `textgreek` is dependent on `greek-fontenc`. However, `textlive-lang-greek` is not listed as a dependency of `texlive-latex-extra`.

If you are using a version with this issue, the solution is to manually install `texlive-lang-greek`:

```
sudo apt install texlive-lang-greek
```

Comment: I believe you meant `sudo aptitude install texlive-lang-greek`, without second 't' in 'texlive'. Otherwise this solution works!

Comment: This fixes the problem on `macports` as well: `sudo port install texlive-lang-greek`.

Answer (score 8):

Arch Linux solution:

## pacman -Syuu texlive-langgreek

Comment: The questions is about MacTeX, not Arch Linux.

Comment: @HenriMenke still, useful for arch users googling the same error message

Answer (score 6):

The solution that I found was to also install the *cbfonts* and *cbfonts-fd* packages, as indicated here [greek encodings under lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157316/greek-encodings-under-lyx), besides the two packages indicated by *egreg.* It might have sufficed to install only the cbfonts package but to be sure I also installed cbfonts-fd package.

Note: I am running Fedora so for other distributions and/or OSs, the packages name may differ

Comment: I installed both packages, but this didn't fix it for me. :/

Comment: What is the error message that you are receiving? It should contain information with respect to what additional package(s) is still needed.

Comment: It was the same as was in OP's question before and after installing tohse packages. greek-fontenc is the package that fixed it for me (on OS X if it matters)

Comment: `sudo tlmgr install cbfonts` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing some more additional packages like:

- babel-greek
- greek-fontenc
- cbfonts

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

*Update 2020:*

To solve `textgreek.sty not found`, you need to install `texlive-science`

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-science
```

Further details here: https://ingbrief.wordpress.com/2017/11/12/kubuntu-17-10-latex-textgreek-sty/